# End to end encryption in a mysql database on Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, encryption

I am building a web application that allows users to store and access some data through a .NET web api which connects to a database.

I will be using MySQL on Azure as the database service. What would be the way to enable some form of end to end encryption of the data? Ideally, I would want it to be such that even I as the db creator cannot access user data. Is this possible?

Comment: "What would be the way to enable some form of end to end encryption of the data?" MySQL's [encryption and decryption functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) and InnoDB supports [table based encryption](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-tablespace-encryption.html)  "Ideally, I would want it to be such that even I as the db creator cannot access user data. Is this possible?" No why would you even want that?

Comment: @RaymondNijland You need to lookup the definition of end to end encryption.

Comment: yes i had to do that @LukeJoshuaPark to say MySQL does not support that feature native out off the box..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm referring to your statement about *"No, why would you even want that?"*

Comment: @RaymondNijland for user's privacy, this is a required feature for us

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark any suggestions?

Comment: If you want it you need to program in this feature in the webapplication it self..

Comment: Sure, we have built in tokenized access to the database from the web app. But using the MySQL connection string, I can still access all the databases

Comment: @aks94 did you get any further with your question? We are having a similar requirement in our application. The only way to achieve this (at least as far as i am aware of) is to encrypt and decrypt the related data in the client application using a user- or customer specific key which is not stored in a central place. Only indexed propertys and keys needed to establish a correlation between user/customer and the related encrypted data block are stored unencrypted.